# Split and Merge image animation

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, animation

I want to split image into 2 pieces and then show a text between them and then merge the pieces again into one image and let the text fade out.
[image: Picture of it made in Photoshop]

HTML:

```
<section id="top" class="fullscreen">
      <header class="fullscreen"><img src="img/logo.png" id="logo">
        <div class="icon-scroll"></div>
      </header>
    </section>
```

CSS:

```
#top header {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: only two separate images will do the job)

Comment: @markoffden not necessarily, one can use a single image as have it as a background for two divs while clipping with `width:50%` and background position

Comment: @Aziz true, playing with background position also will do. good tip

Comment: @Aziz I think markoffden meant 2 `<img>`s, not different pngs.

Comment: @DanielCheung question is vague as it is, the OP did not specify in what approach this should be done, and there are many.

Comment: @Aziz The question was not vague. I understood. OP just didn't put enough effort to the question or work.

Comment: @danielcheung it is vague in the sense that we don't know what the OP is having difficulties with, they are asking for someone to solve their problem for them instead of trying and explaining what didn't work

Comment: @Aziz "The whole thing" I know what it feels because I've been in that place. I had no idea what I was going to write because I didn't know anything.

Answer (score 1):

You may create to DIVs which are half width of your image and height of your image. Then set your image as a background for them with different positioning. So you may do it this way...

```
<div class="half left"></div>
<div class="half right"></div>

.half {
    width: 200px; /* half of your image width */
    height: 400px; /* your image height */ 
}

.left {
    background: url('path/to/your/image.png') top left no-repeat;
}

.right {
    background: url('path/to/your/image.png') top right no-repeat;
}
```